# Confusion when using @model in Razor with Http Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have an app, mostly generated at this point using ET 6 DB First + controller/views scaffolding. I am conceptual confused with posting from Razor with my controller. Basically my data is not making it past the `DOM`.

Here is my controller: (don't mind the validation setting, this is not a public facing app)

```
namespace RegTeg.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private VRIIntegrationEntities db = new VRIIntegrationEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.ApplicationNames.ToList());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        // [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "appName")] RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName newAppName)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ApplicationNames.Add(newAppName);
                db.SaveChanges();   //fails here due to a null column
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(newAppName);
        }

    }
}
```

So I have my Index in which I deliver a list to the view so I can display the data from my DB to the user upon visiting the page. On this page there is also a post, they can add something to the DB. I pass it an instance of my model and then insert into the table. So that's all nice (so I think).

Now for my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName>

<div>
    <select class="applicationSelect">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.appName)
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName appModel = new RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName();
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <h3>Add New Application for Testing:</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => appModel.appName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => appModel.appName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => appModel.appName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I pass in my strongly typed model. Get the data in my foreach loop... okay, that's done, now I want to do a post to my server and add new data to my db. I create a new instance of the model, pull the data from my input and boom, submit it. But the problem is, the data is `null`. I have a hunch that it has to do with my `@model` declaration. For example, the post needs a `@model RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName` however I thought there is no need when I declare the new instance later on in my view? I hope I articulated myself well enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like initially you pass a List but in the post you are only passing a single item to the view, but your view is expecting a list.

Comment: @MikeC. That's what I was thinking, so how would you recommend doing both? Pass in the database VRIIntegrationEntity. Build a list and a single model instance within the view from that? I guess I am not sure on how to handle both?

Comment: In your post ActionMethod, construct a list and add that single item to it, then continue to pass a list as your view is expecting.

Comment: Actually, this is your index. You probably just need to copy what you did in the ActionMethod that's working. You still want to display everything right, not just a single item. Just a guess. If this doesn't make sense I'll post an answer, just seems pointless as I'm pretty sure you can figure this out yourself.

Comment: @MikeC. ya I get it, thanks. However this was just one of my issues. I am still passing a null value into my database on `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Look at your HTML for the textbox where you enter the value. The NAME attribute needs to match your variable name in the controller. I'd get rid of the binding stuff that you're doing there and just make sure that the names match.

Comment: @MikeC. Thanks man. If you want to just throw all that explanation in an answer, no example needed, I'll make sure to mark it as the answer. If not no worries. Have a good day.

Comment: I will do that as I prefer for questions to have marked answers, but no sweat if you get busy and forget :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

I'm guessing that you want to still display all of your applications, so I'd recommend you just model your post after what you did initially:

```
[HttpPost]
// [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "appName")] RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName newAppName)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ApplicationNames.Add(newAppName);
        db.SaveChanges();   //fails here due to a null column
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    //continue to return a list as your view is expecting
    //if you REALLY want only the item that you just created, then construct a list, 
    //add that to it, and return that instead of the full list
    return View(db.ApplicationNames.ToList());
}
```

Problem 2:

Have a look at your HTML. What you need to do, is make sure sure that the NAME attribute on your textbox is the same as the variable name for your ActionMethod. For example, if your textbox is like this:

```
<input type="text" name="appName" id="appName" />
```

Then I would recommend getting rid of the binding stuff that you have and just do this:

```
[HttpPost]
// [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName appName)
{
    ... existing code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem are you use two models, in the view:

1) model IEnumerable is model for a list.
2) model RegTeg.Models.ApplicationName is model for one element.

well exist differnts ways to fixed that, I like make the form in a PartialView,

more info et others solutions about using multiple models in a view http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC